# Chrome on android: touchevent not work on a-entity click

Tags: google-chrome, aframe, touch-event, ontouch

The problem of question is: click event via touch click on mobile from VR mode 
not work from android Chrome 79+.
Otherwords touchstart event does not fired on entity from VR mode.
Google Vr services are installed and enabled.

The goal a-entity should be clickable in Chrome latest 79+
on user click (VR mode touch click from mobile)

Links to whole code:
here 2 config simple app:
https://4dkly.csb.app/ (config: fuse  3.6sec; but click on entity does Not work from chrome vr)
https://codesandbox.io/s/aframe-example-4dkly?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=white

https://12k87.csb.app/ (cursor color red; fuse turned off , cursor still does not work)
https://codesandbox.io/s/aframe-example-12k87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
 Could you please take a look for any of this example, and tell what to do, to make chrome latest, vr mode touch click.
Any new good approach new api is also ok.

Here code excerpt

````
 <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.1/aframe.min.js"></script>

    <a-scene main> 
      <a-sphere position="0 2 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"> </a-sphere>
 <!-- ... -->

      <a-camera id="camera" camera rotation>
        <a-entity
          id="cursor"
          cursor="fuse:false"
          position="0 0 -1"
          material="color: #111;"

        >
        </a-entity>
      </a-camera>
//simple event on click 
 document.querySelector("a-box").addEventListener("click", () => {
   alert("box");
});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described is expected. Touch events are disabled by the browser when entering immersive mode via WebXR as it's the case for Chrome 79+ and content served over `https`. There are new APIs in the works to enable interactivity while presenting in AR. You can find additional details in this blog post: https://aframe.io/blog/webxr-ar-module/

On devices that don't have a native WebXR implementation VR mode relies on the full screen API and touchevents are available.

I don't recommend relying on screen input while in VR and use a [fuse based cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html#properties_fuse)

Comment: interesting behavior: i've debug event click, event touchstart in different browsers in VR mode: while event touchstart does not works  in any android mobile; event window. click works on FF, opera touch, samsung mobile,  but not works in Chrome. the goal of our client is to make touch under VR mode (for inner reason, they just dont like fuse cursor). Differece is Any chance to toogle old behavior on chrome with XR ? tried chrome://flags WebVR enabled, but still no toch in chrome. What to reccomend our client if not fuse? to use firefox? much thank you for keeping the word and still answering!

Comment: we've checked: on app request: there will be invisible points, what can be revealed only on click event. If there any solution to make chrome VR work as usual?

Comment: as Klaus Weidner shows, this example works ok from latest chrome. https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/input-selection.html

Comment: Klaus example uses new APIs mentioned in the blog post above that are not yet standard. As mentioned there’s no way to rely on touch events in VR mode at the moment.

Comment: The main purpose of our app is : to reveal hidden point on chosen click. fuse cursor simple does not work here because user can be occasionally reveal point by fuse)

Comment: here 2 config simple app: what should be work in Chrom by entity click 
https://4dkly.csb.app/ (fuse  3.6sec; but click on entity does Not work from chrome vr)
https://codesandbox.io/s/aframe-example-4dkly?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=white


https://12k87.csb.app/ (cursor color red; fuse turned off , cursor still does not work)  
https://codesandbox.io/s/aframe-example-12k87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark Could you please take a look for any of this example?

Comment: that is good for research https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-samples ; if it is help to make click for chrome , i'll try to do that)

Comment: Diego, i've wrote to discord chat. if we find working solution with touch, can post it here.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to catch touch events in AR mode on Chrome Android?