# How to select tapped model three.js webxr

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, augmented-reality

I am implementing rotation functionality to models added to the scene in ar (webxr) , currently I   implement it only on the recently added model but I want to let user do it with any model present so I need to select the tapped model(I use touchstart event for this) , I use raycaster and check  if intersection to object but it not works , do I need to update camera ? or what , here is the code:

```
// loc is vec2d , I add rotation to model in rotatemodel
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    touchDown=true;
                    touchX = e.touches[0].pageX;
                    touchY = e.touches[0].pageY;

                loc.x = touchX ;
                loc.y = -  touchY;

                raycaster.setFromCamera( loc , camera );

                const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    if ( rotatemodel != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

                        rotatemodel = intersects[ 0 ].object;

                    }

                } 
                },false)
```

Comment: I can share complete code if required

Answer (score 1):

Touch events like `touchstart` are disabled by the browser when entering immersive mode via WebXR. So you can't use them to implement interactivity in your app.

More information in: [Chrome on android: touchevent not work on a-entity click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740484/chrome-on-android-touchevent-not-work-on-a-entity-click)

Comment: I've used touchstart with the help of dom overlay and it works perfectly for rotation , so I think touchstart work maybe i am wrong

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that you are using the WebXR DOM Overlays Module.

Comment: can you help me fix this

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to solve this issue.